# Apexchart disappearing when changing page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I have a graphic chart displaying in my main page. The graph is displaying normally, but when I'm switching to a page within my application and getting back to the main page, the graph disappears.

I'm using a routing system in React to switch between my pages.

**The react component of the graph that's rendering :**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'; 

class Widget1 extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div> 

                    {/*begin::Stats Widget 1*/}
                    <div className="card card-custom gutter-b">
                        {/*begin::Body*/}
                        <div className="card-body p-0">
                          <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between card-spacer flex-grow-1">
                            <span className="symbol symbol-circle symbol-50 symbol-light-danger mr-2">
                              <span className="symbol-label">
                                <span className="svg-icon svg-icon-xl svg-icon-danger">
                                  {/*begin::Svg Icon | path:assets/media/svg/icons/Layout/Layout-4-blocks.svg*/}
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">
                                    <g stroke="none" strokeWidth={1} fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                                      <rect x={0} y={0} width={24} height={24} />
                                      <rect fill="#000000" x={4} y={4} width={7} height={7} rx="1.5" />
                                      <path d="M5.5,13 L9.5,13 C10.3284271,13 11,13.6715729 11,14.5 L11,18.5 C11,19.3284271 10.3284271,20 9.5,20 L5.5,20 C4.67157288,20 4,19.3284271 4,18.5 L4,14.5 C4,13.6715729 4.67157288,13 5.5,13 Z M14.5,4 L18.5,4 C19.3284271,4 20,4.67157288 20,5.5 L20,9.5 C20,10.3284271 19.3284271,11 18.5,11 L14.5,11 C13.6715729,11 13,10.3284271 13,9.5 L13,5.5 C13,4.67157288 13.6715729,4 14.5,4 Z M14.5,13 L18.5,13 C19.3284271,13 20,13.6715729 20,14.5 L20,18.5 C20,19.3284271 19.3284271,20 18.5,20 L14.5,20 C13.6715729,20 13,19.3284271 13,18.5 L13,14.5 C13,13.6715729 13.6715729,13 14.5,13 Z" fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" />
                                    </g>
                                  </svg>
                                  {/*end::Svg Icon*/}
                                </span>
                              </span>
                            </span>
                            <div className="d-flex flex-column text-right">
                              <span className="text-dark-75 font-weight-bolder font-size-h3">12000 dh</span>
                              <span className="text-muted font-weight-bold mt-2">Revenu hebdomadaire</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="kt_stats_widget_11_chart" className="card-rounded-bottom" data-color="danger" style={{height: 150}} />
                        </div>
                        {/*end::Body*/}
                      </div>
                      {/*end::Stats Widget 1*/}


            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Widget1;
```

**The javascript of the graph ( Months, color etc .. ) :**

```
var _initStatsWidget11 = function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("kt_stats_widget_11_chart");

        var height = parseInt(KTUtil.css(element, 'height'));
        var color = KTUtil.hasAttr(element, 'data-color') ? KTUtil.attr(element, 'data-color') : 'success';

        if (!element) {
            return;
        }

        var options = {
            series: [{
                name: 'Profit',
                data: [40, 40, 30, 30, 35, 35, 50]
            }],
            chart: {
                type: 'area',
                height: 150,
                toolbar: {
                    show: false
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                sparkline: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {},
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            fill: {
                type: 'solid',
                opacity: 1
            },
            stroke: {
                curve: 'smooth',
                show: true,
                width: 3,
                colors: [KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['theme']['base'][color]]
            },
            xaxis: {
                categories: ['Jan','Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Aug', 'Sep'],
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false,
                },
                axisTicks: {
                    show: false
                },
                labels: {
                    show: false,
                    style: {
                        colors: KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['gray']['gray-500'],
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        fontFamily: KTApp.getSettings()['font-family']
                    }
                },
                crosshairs: {
                    show: false,
                    position: 'front',
                    stroke: {
                        color: KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['gray']['gray-300'],
                        width: 1,
                        dashArray: 3
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: undefined,
                    offsetY: 0,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        fontFamily: KTApp.getSettings()['font-family']
                    }
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 55,
                labels: {
                    show: false,
                    style: {
                        colors: KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['gray']['gray-500'],
                        fontSize: '12px',
                        fontFamily: KTApp.getSettings()['font-family']
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                normal: {
                    filter: {
                        type: 'none',
                        value: 0
                    }
                },
                hover: {
                    filter: {
                        type: 'none',
                        value: 0
                    }
                },
                active: {
                    allowMultipleDataPointsSelection: false,
                    filter: {
                        type: 'none',
                        value: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: KTApp.getSettings()['font-family']
                },
                y: {
                    formatter: function (val) {
                        return "$" + val + " thousands"
                    }
                }
            },
            colors: [KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['theme']['light'][color]],
            markers: {
                colors: [KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['theme']['light'][color]],
                strokeColor: [KTApp.getSettings()['colors']['theme']['base'][color]],
                strokeWidth: 3
            }
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(element, options);
        chart.render();
    }
```

**App.js for pages switching :**

```
import Home from './pages/home';
import HeaderMenu from './components/HeaderMenu';
import Menu from './components/menu';
import Widget1 from './components/Widget1';
import Patient from './pages/patients';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom'; 
 


const App = () => { 
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>

          <Menu /> 
          <HeaderMenu />  
            <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}>
                <Home />
            </Route>

            <Route path='/patients' component={Patient}>
                <Patient />
            </Route> 
          </Switch> 
          
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
    
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where are you rendering the charts? Also, you should check out [react-apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/).

Comment: The chart is rendered in home.js using `<Widget1 /> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start your application by `/patients` first then go to your app component then this wont work as well.
So, this is not a problem of going back and forth. your chart init function is being called in the beginning somewhere in your code so when your chart component renders at first the code gets the dom element and initializes it. But on navigation only the component code runs leaving the reinitialization behind. So, call the init function in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle of Home component where you need your chart.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. But as a newbie in React I don't exactly know what to add in the `componentDidMount`, is it just the initialisation as it's done the the JS of the chart ?

Comment: yes call that function that you did in your js file.

Comment: When calling the same function in the js file into the home component, a lot of variables are not defnied such as `KTApp` and `ApexCharts` . Those are not initialised anywhere in the js file but I think in another separate file. Should I export everything from differents sources ?

Comment: You should use modules it will be lot easier. 
You should use react apexcharts. There are lots of examples here
https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/

Comment: Yea that what I will do. The existing code came from an HTML template, that I'm trying to convert to react, so the graph is a little prettier there. Anyway thank you because I know now where I had the problem atleast.

Comment: Great. Hope you can fix your  issue now.

Comment: I did it it worked :) ! Thank you again for the insights !